# An old chromedriver.exe (2.36) works fine with all newer chrome browser versions without needing to update it. How is this possible?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using a *selenium java testng* project. Dependencies including chromedriver.exe are part of source code as of now and in the process of moving to ant + ivy.

Current *selenium server standalone version* being used is *3.14.0* and *chromedriver.exe* has never been updated since 2 years (2.36.540470). However, *chrome browser* version in my machine is up to date (*84.0.4147.89*).

**Question:** Tests work just fine. Please help me how is this old *chromedriver* able to work with the newer *chrome browser* versions ?

Here is the driver initialization code:

```
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\chromedriver.exe");     
            HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", "somepath");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: "How is this old chromedriver able to work with the newer chrome browser versions?"  It shouldn't work.  If it does, please let me know what version you have there, because it'd be nice not to have to update the darned thing all the time.  Are you sure maven isn't updating it during the build?

Comment: @pcalkins Not using maven. Project is using the downloaded copy of chromedriver.exe which is not updated since 2 years. Unfortunately, I don't have the version number as it's name was renamed. Also, selenium server standalone jar being used is an old version - 3.14.0. Not sure what makes it work with newer chrome versions.

Comment: include your driver initialization code.  That may give a clue as to what's happening here.

Comment: The question is too broad as per SO standards. Please [edit the question](/posts/63043003/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think DesiredCapabilities is deprecated in new chromedriver versions, so does seem to be an older version.  Try double-clicking on it.  It should show a version number in console... and check the version of the launched browser.

Comment: You can use `chromedriver.exe -version` to find the version.

Comment: One thing you're setting that I'm not familiar with is this: options.addArguments("test-type");  Maybe that allows you to use any chromedriver version?  What does that option do?

Comment: I see 2.36.540470 in console after double clicking on chromedriver.exe

Comment: @pcalkins I removed line - options.addArguments("test-type") from code as I am not familiar either and executed. Verified that the chrome browser version is 84.0.4147.89 and chromedriver.exe is 2.36.540470 in selenium node console during execution (I am using selenium grid).

Comment: that's very interesting... are the tests running locally or are you initializing another remote driver?

Comment: @pcalkins It worked both ways - local run from eclipse IDE without using Se Grid and also using Se Grid with remote web driver on Jenkins. I verified version of the test browser in both cases - local machine and remote node as up to date.

Comment: I'll run some tests on my machine when I have the time.  I found a download of that version here:  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.36/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218479/discussion-between-newuser-and-pcalkins).

Comment: I tested it and it does launch the browser and load the correct initial page, but then it seems to lose its connection with the browser.  This was with Selenium Standalone Server 3.14.159... with 3.14.0 it launched the browser and loaded the correct page, but then I think the driver crashed.  Hard to say if I had the correct dependencies for that version of Selenium Server though.  Wasn't running from an IDE at the time.  It's actually a little unusual that the browser even launched ,I would have expected the driver to crash right away.

Comment: I don't have any additional dependencies specific to selenium except a single selenium server standalone jar of version 3.14.0 and chromedriver.exe binary.